# Can not make C++ code faster than Matlab code for reading and parsing Ascii file data

Tags: c++, matlab

I am transforming my Matlab code to C++ code for faster performance and larger data analysis. For just reading the input data file and reformatting it, Matlab is still way faster.

The first step of my program is to read an ASCII input data file and then reshape the data into a 3D matrix. In Matlab, I use "importdata" built-in function for reading data and "reshape" built-in function to reformat the numeric data into 3D matrix. In C++, for reading data (and after many days of search) I am using two methods for reading the whole file into a string from an input file stream as shown below (code#1 and code#2), this is fast enough
(the second method is better than the first one),but the slow performance comes when I try to extract numeric data from the file string as integers (code#3). For reshaping the data into 3D matrix, I simply used 3 loops as shown in (code#4) which is also very slow compared to Matlab "reshape"
function. I tried to replace the ASCII file with a binary one which is read very fast by C++ "file.read" (code#5) but the reshaping part is causing the overall performance to be slow.

So my questions are:

- Is there a faster way to get the numeric data from the ASCII file?
- Is there a faster way to reshape a vector of integers into 3D matrix?

I have been searching in these problems for a while (Prefer not to say how long :D) and any help is appreciated.

## Variables declaration

```
stringstream buffer;
ifstream inFile;
string fileString;
int temp1;
string temp2;
vector<int> vec (n,0); // n is determined from the input data size
vector<vector<vector<int>>> volume;
int D1,D2,D3;    // 3D matrix dimensions determined from user input.
```

- Code#1 :  (Read ASCII into string 1)

  ```
  buffer << inFile.rdbuf();
  fileString = buffer.str();
  ```
- Code#2 : (Read ASCII into string 2)

  ```
  inFile.seekg(0, ios::end);
  fileString.resize((int)inFile.tellg());
  inFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
  inFile.read(&fileString[0], fileString.size());
  inFile.close();
  buffer << fileString;
  ```
- Code#3 : (Get numeric data from string into a vector of integers)

  ```
  for(int i = 0;i <n ;++i){
  buffer >> temp2; 
  if(stringstream(temp2) >> temp1)
  vec.at(i) = temp1;
  }
  ```
- Code#4 : (Rehape vector into 3D matrix)

  ```
  volume.resize(D1, vector<vector<int> >(D2, vector<int>(D3)));
  int n = ;
      for (int i = 0; i < D1; ++i) {
          for (int j = 0; j < D2; ++j) {
              for (int k = 0; k < D3; ++k) {
                   volume.at(i).at(j).at(k)= (int)vec.at(n);
                  ++n;
              }
          }
      }
  ```
- Code#5 : (Read binary file into vector of unsigned integers 8 bits)

  ```
  inFile.seekg(0, ios_base::end);
  size_t siz = inFile.tellg();
  inFile.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);
  vec.resize(siz / sizeof(uint8_t));
  inFile.read((char*)&vec[0], siz);
  inFile.close();
  ```

Comment: A) Compile with optimizations. B) Use references instead of copy-by-value.

Comment: Don't use `volume.at(i).at(j).at(k)` use `volume[i][j][k]`.

Comment: Most of Matlab's functions are written in C++ for performance reasons. They are tight and often use multiple threads where available. So no surprise they do this faster. BTW, vectors of vectors are a particularly inefficient design approach.

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing how much more performance you are able to get out of C++ over Matlab.

Comment: MATLAB doesn't copy data when reshaping. Why do you need to copy data in C++? Do the same thing as MATLAB: store your 3D array as a simple `std::vector<int>`, and compute linear index from 3D coordinates: `i + j*width + k*width*height`.

Comment: Thank you all. 
@tadman   A) I do not know about compiling with optimization I will start reading, any links would be great. 
B) I tried this `volume[i][j][k] = (int)vptr->at(n);` , but did not cause any difference. 
@Galik  used it. 
@doug I know that Matlab functions are professionally written, but the only reason I am transferring to C++ is to get better performance, especially because I will deal with huge data sizes.
@Eljay actually right now Matlab is 7x faster than C++ :( .

Comment: @CrisLuengo  usually the 3D matrix is required for the next function,  I am not sure yet in C++ , but if not , this will save a lot of time.

Comment: If you're using a function that expects a `vector<vector<vector<>>>` as input, you need to either rewrite that function or look for a better library. A 3D array should be implemented as a `vector<>`. This is the way MATLAB does it, and it's the way all good software does it. The only reason to use a `vector<vector<>>` is if each inner vector is of different length. If they're all the same length, as in a 3D array, you should definitely not spread it around the memory space and add all these levels of indirection. That's just bad.

Comment: Read up on how your compiler enables optimization and what the optimization levels do. For GCC-style compilers it's often `-O3` as a flag, but there are many more options. Debug builds are often *considerably* slower than optimized ones. The difference can be dramatic.

Comment: If you are trying to improve performance, seriously consider not using iostreams. The lower-level C file I/O is still there and used by many, for a good reason.

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply. @tadman A) The vector is a member of a class, and member functions are using it, maybe that is why there is no difference when I used copy-by-value and copy-by-reference.
B) WoW this is magic, I do not know how this works or what does it indicate but the difference when I used compiling with optimization is unbelievable.
For data that will be reshaped in 571*537*501 3D matrix:
- Default compiling :  time elapsed ~= 137 sec.
- compiling with optimization: time elapsed ~= 1 sec. 
What is this!!!! Thank you tadman.

Comment: @CrisLuengo 
The 3D matrix data will be used in a marching cubes algorithm to extract surfaces, in Matlab this function requires a 3D matrix, but yes I think you are right the functions may be operating on vectors behind the scene, I will check.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig|
I am not sure, but I noticed that to load the data using iostreams is fast enough, my problem was to read numeric data from a string into a vector of integers (code#3).

Comment: Debug builds are often vastly slower than fully optimized builds. Benchmarking a debug build is basically pointless. Only the optimized code matters.

Comment: there's a reason they're called "optimization". Production code should never be built in debug mode because there are lots of things added to help debugging (like address sanitizer, heap overflow or stack smashing detection) beside unoptimized code. When the compiler optimizes the code it does tons of things like loop unrolling, loop reversing, auto-vectorizing, branch reorganizing, deadcode/unused variables removing... that makes a vast difference. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler

Comment: @4Light: “compiling with optimization” (as in, any at all) is not a topic for which you should ask for “any links”—it is a basic and fundamental feature of almost all compilers and something you can find out about faster than you can ask us (let alone waiting for us to answer).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the underlying problem is not related to the content of the question.

Comment: Reading the whole file into a string is probably not a good idea either (not that `istream` is known for being very fast).